# I want to convert the following code in Foreach to Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    sb.Append(@"<div class='item'> <img class='img-responsive' src='images/gallary/"+ dr["Image_name"].ToString() + @"'  height='140' width='180' />
        <h2>Lorem Ipspspsum</h2>
      </div> ");
}
```

Using this for each loop I'm dynamically adding image to webpage retrieved from database. Can this loop be converted to Linq? if yes then how?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Why? don't like that solution or someone told that was cool to use Linq?

Comment: I agree with @mjoia, this is code is very legible, you don't have to use Linq

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why to change to a linq solution. IMO it is not more readable but to do so: Use `.Select` for the loop and `string.Concat` to combine all the strings together:

```
var result = string.Concat(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Select(dr => 
    @"<div class='item'> <img class='img-responsive' src='images/gallary/"+ dr["Image_name"].ToString() + @"'  height='140' width='180' /><h2>Lorem Ipspspsum</h2></div> "));
```

In addition you can use string interpolation this way:

```
var result = string.Concat(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Select(dr => 
    $@"<div class='item'> <img class='img-responsive' src='images/gallary/{dr["Image_name"].ToString()}'  height='140' width='180' /><h2>Lorem Ipspspsum</h2></div> "));
```

*I'd probably add the string interpolation in any case, even if not changing it to a linq solution*

Comment: But with Select you're using Projection, I think he wanted to use ds.Tables[0].Rows.ForEach(row => {
   // sb append
})

Maybe needs a .ToList() there.. didn't try it

Comment: @rmjoia - no because projection is what I want :) I want to format each row to a specific string and then concat all of them. `ForEach` executes a void method on each item in a list. That is not what I want

Comment: I know you do.. but when Hermagni asked to conver the loop I assumed he wanted to use the foreach, of course your solution works and maybe is even a better design, there are many ways to solve the problem. :) don't take me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but in my opinion Aggregate would be the 'most linq'(it's the same as reduce in other languages). Aggregate is intended to map multiple objects in to a single object and since you are transforming an array of rows to a single StringBuilder this will do what you want. In regards to the other solutions they work and are good but I would say Aggregate(or Reduce) is the most linq way of doing it since it's the most functional solution of all(but that doesn't mean better).

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, dr) => a.Append(@"<div class='item'> <img class='img-responsive' src='images/gallary/"+ dr["Image_name"].ToString() + @"'  height='140' width='180' />
        <h2>Lorem Ipspspsum</h2>
      </div> "));
```

But is this better then foreach no it will to pretty much the same thing as your code under the hood.

Comment: It would be good to explain why you think Aggregate is a better way

Comment: @GiladGreen I tried to make more clear what I meant by 'best', I wanted to say 'most linq' since this is what aggregate is used for.